# Change page size on command line

Tags: geometry, page

Is it possible to build a given LaTeX document with a different page size?

Best would be to somehow "override" the page size on command line when calling `pdflatex`. Second best would be a bullet proof way to insert the necessary command "on the fly" into the document. Third best would be something that at least works with the `geometry` package.

Comment: what do you mean by "given" here? It is easy to write a document (or document class) that takes an option defined on the commandline, Harder (not really possible) to have a commandline that over-rides the document settings of any supplied document, however they are defined

Comment: I am looking for the second one. I would like to reformat a lot of TeX documents from different sources, and I wonder whether I can automate that.

Comment: You can (from the commandline) drop in a new page size via `\AtBeginDocument` and hope that does something reasonable, but if the document has display math aligments with lines broken for the original size, or images included natural size not scaled to proportions of `\textwith` or the moon is in the wrong phase and you run out of luck, then the result will not be reasonable. (Commandline not an issue, same would be true if you allowed yourself to edit just the document preamble)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks a lot, I will watch the phases of the moon closely while trying your suggestion.